# аналогия двумерного массива С в Python

Tags: python, c

В `С` я, для вывода каждого элемента двумерного массива пишу следующий код:

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<N;j++){
        printf("%d", a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("/n");
}
```

Как это интерпритировать в Python .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```py
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        print(a[i][j], end = " ")
    print()
```

либо так:

```py
for i in range(N):
    print(*arr[i])
```

Comment: `for row in a: print(*row)`

Answer (score 2):

В Питоне принято избегать обращения к спискам (тут массивы так называют) по индексам. Дословный перевод вашей программы с C (с некоторыми исправлениями, так как ваш код работает не так как вы представляете) будет таким:

```
for row in a:
    for v in row:
        print(v, end=' ')
    print()
```

Это не самый лучший способ. Лишние пробелы в конце строк - неаккуратно. Лучше печатать строку целиком. С точки зрения программиста на C тут перерасход памяти под строку. С точки зрения питониста все отлично. `map` применяет `str` ко всем элементам `row`, делая из них строки. `join` склеивает строки через пробелы:

```
for row in a:
    print(' '.join(map(str, row)))
```

Кроме прямой строковой обработки можно воспользоваться хитростью, которую предоставляет функция `print`. Синаксис `f(*lst)` означает "преврати список `lst` в аргументы функции `f`". Это именно хитрость, далеко на ней не уедешь, но знать её надо:

```
for row in a:
    print(*row)
```